# Assembly mov instruction is not recognized

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, addressing-mode

I was taught that I could use this instruction:

```
movl (arr,%r8,4),%eax
```

in case I wanted to do:

```
%eax=Mem[arr+4*%r8]
```

However this command doesn't seem to be recognized at all and I am getting an error:

```
Error: Found ',', expected ')'
Error: junk ',%r8,4)' after expression
```

I can't understand. Is this a real instruction or not?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.  Try `movl arr(,%r8,4), %eax` instead.  Also note that it's called “instruction,” not “command.”

Comment: @fuz From what I can tell this does Mem[%eax]=Mem[arr+4*%r8]? I get a seg fault for trying to approach the address of %eax using this instruction.

Comment: No, this loads `eax` (the register) with the content of the memory at address `arr+4*r8`.  It does not load the memory at address `eax`.

Comment: For assembler there are two common, but different syntaxes: Intel & AT&T. Please check, which one you should use: https://imada.sdu.dk/~kslarsen/dm546/Material/IntelnATT.htm

Comment: Check the error message: it is not complaining about `mov`.

Comment: displacement (the symbol) goes outside the parens; only registers and the scale factor go in the parens.